# How can you recognize an armored enemy?

Tags: 10000000

I'm trying to meet the in-game goal of killing an armoured enemy in less than five seconds. The dungeon has orcs, demons, ninjas and a treant, but there seems to be no way to tell which is armoured.

Is there a way to tell a monster is armoured? Is it up to each individual monster or is an entire class armoured? (For example, all orcs, all demons, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are about to start a run, and you are on the screen where you choose difficulty, see your quests etc., you also see a list of your enemies.

As I understand it, it goes Armored, Neutral, Ranged, Boss-type. So the topmost monster will be the armored one (Golem, Demon, Fallen Soldier etc.).

Comment: I've started playing through the game again, and that pattern works every time. :)

Did you notice this or find out somehow?

Comment: It is ultimately a qualified guess. Noticed a pattern with boss being last and ranged always being before that (as the ranged ones are easy to identify) and from having tested a couple it seemed to hold. No actual information about this in the game as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Armored enemies are the ones resistant to physical damage and weak to magic.

Comment: But how can you tell what enemies meet this criteria?

Comment: This is technically correct but not helpful or the answer to the question. How can you tell an enemy is armored before attacking them, so you can know to use magic/unleash items to kill it quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, those are the purple guys with the shield, yet I didn't play for a rather long time.

If they actually can't be distinguished anymore, I'd suggest you to just rambo in and pray to lady luck.

Have a nice day ~Crowley